# Node Express Mongoose MongoDB CORS failure

Tags: node.js, curl, mongoose, debian, cors

I am using Node/Express/Mongoose/MongoDB on a Debian VPS webserver but for some reason the online CORS request is not firing.  Let me just say that everything works perfectly on my local server.

When I upload it to my Debian VPS webserver however the cors request never goes through.  I know this because the debug logs never fire.  The MongoDB server is running AND the node/express server is running.  I have npm reinstalled express/mongoose and even the cors addon MANY times and do not think it's an issue with those...

I have tested things on the server with cURL -H w/ the -origin flags.  THE RESPONSES RETURN CORRECTLY in the console.  This leads me to believe that the CORS requests are being blocked somehow (maybe by the browsers??) and the express servers are never even reached. I have tried starting browsers with no security flags to no avail also...  ONE strange fact is that when the responses do return w/ cURL, they sometimes list different origins even though I specify one origin with the flag. Confusing...

I have tried changing access-origins MANY different times and ways.  I have tried allowing all of them.  I have tried allowing the ones specific to the requests... I have tried using the apache2 header mod and using an .htaccess file to allow cors.  I have also tried the PHP header for it to no avail.

url:  www.kensnote.com
Browser error responses are as follows:
**Chromium-browser**: "Failed to load resource"
**Firefox:**  Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:10005/threadpreview. (Reason: CORS request failed).

Firefox Firebug Request Headers:

> Accept     application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
>   Accept-Encoding    gzip, deflate Accept-Language   en-US,en;q=0.5
>   Cache-Control  max-age=0 Connection    keep-alive DNT  1 Host 
>   localhost:10005 If-None-Match  W/"ssUy2L+Up13MCm2LISgPtQ==" Origin
>   http://www.kensnote.com Referer    http://www.kensnote.com/
>   User-Agent     Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101
>   Firefox/39.0

Answer (score 0):

> In a browser implementing CORS, each cross-origin GET or POST request
>   is preceded by an OPTIONS request that checks whether the GET or POST
>   is OK.

Basically, for CORS, Firefox will send a preflight options check before the real request.
In your server code, you should send an OK response to the `OPTIONS` request. Check the following example code that can be used in a route (or middleware):

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");  
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PATCH, POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
if ('OPTIONS' === req.method) { 
  return res.send(200);
}
```

Comment: I thought that I have tried this but I will diligently try it again.  Unfortunately I will have to try it later as I am not on an internet connection that allows my to log into my server atm.  Thank you for your response and I'll give it a million upvotes if it works :)  (I can prob only give it one lol)

Comment: I'm sorry but that DOES NOT correct the problem...  I'm wondering if it could be something with the VPS Debian server OR their firewall security??  This is really becoming a frustrating thing....

Comment: just as a sanity check, are you also setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` ?
Access-Control-Allow-Origin, "*" would obviously give permission to all domains, which isn't desirable, but could be used in the interim to see if that solves the issue.

Comment: Yes I know it's not desirable but I HAVE been testing Access-Control-Allow-Origin, "*" and it has the same result: failed. sigh

Comment: and it fails on all browsers that I've tried so it's probably not a ff issue but ff at least gives a better error.  Chromium just gives a "fetch error".  I've also tried calling things through a json/jsonp ajax call which also works on my local but NOT on the server still

Comment: Ok, is your static content being delivered from node.js, or from another webserver (say apache?)

Comment: static content is being delivered from apache2 server.  Only using Node with routes gathered from mongoose/mongoDB content.  Would that cause conflicts?

Comment: Could very well be. You will actually need to set all of the CORS headers in your Apache config, and ensure you proxy calls to your node server through Apache. http://awesometoast.com/cors/ has a decent example of doing this for CORS